# WebView denied access to webpage resources in Sandboxed Mac App

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, sandbox

I recently began implementing Mac App Store sandboxing (ugh) and noticed that saved HTML archives loaded into a WebView do not render referenced resources.  For example, a saved webpage, MyPage.html, can reference styles.css, image.jpg, and script.js in a corresponding MyPage_files folder (Google Chrome's save "Webpage, Complete" convention):

- MyPage.html
- MyPage_files/styles.css
- MyPage_files/image.jpg
- MyPage_files/script.js

However, after loading the MyPage.html file into a WebView, the Console.app reports errors like this:

```
sandboxd: deny file-read-data /Users/user/Desktop/MyPage_files/styles.css
sandboxd: deny file-read-data /Users/user/Desktop/MyPage_files/image.jpg
sandboxd: deny file-read-data /Users/user/Desktop/MyPage_files/script.js
```

Should this be considered a bug, or is it something that is just a limitation of WebViews within the sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limitation of the original sandbox design, but it's one that Apple has (at least partially) fixed.

Apple engineers have discussed the new solution in at least two places, but unfortunately, I believe they're both "prerelease" information sources that nobody outside of Apple is allowed to talk about in public places like this.

If you have a paid Mac Developer Program membership, go to the [Application Sandboxing forum](https://devforums.apple.com/community/mac/pre/appsandbox).

I believe "The OS X App Sandbox" video from [The WWDC 2012 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) is available without a paid Mac Developer Program membership.

Also, keep in mind that you will need some kind of fallback, unless you're willing to require all of your users to upgrade to a new version of OS X. You should definitely file a bug with Apple explaining what you need, and post about it on the forums. You can post about it on the non-prerelease forums, because you're asking how to do this on Lion, which doesn't involve any confidential information.

One last point: if you're creating the archives yourself, you can save them so that there's a MyPage bundle with the .html file and _files subdirectory inside it; then, when the user selects your bundle, you'll have access to everything. But of course this won't work if you're trying to open, e.g., archives created by Safari.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the legality of sharing "prerelease" information?

Comment: Not very much, no. They stamp headers like "Apple Confidential Information" on the prerelease dev forums, have warnings like "Do not share information from this site" on the prerelease dev documentation, etc. Apple employees have referred to the information that's only available to paid MDP members as being "under effective NDA". And if you talk about prerelease features on the non-prerelease forums, Apple employees chastise you and sometimes your posts get deleted. I have no idea what the actual legal force of any of this is—and even if I had a guess, IANAL, so you shouldn't trust it.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I was confused how that related to your comment about the sandbox limitation.  I get it now.  You meant to say that Apple has partially fixed it, but you can't discuss or mention any details about *what* has been fixed because that's "prerelease" information.

Comment: Exactly. Sorry that wasn't clear. I'll edit the answer to make things make more sense.

Comment: One solution to this would be to use security-scoped bookmarks (in this case: document-scoped bookmarks), as described in the [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16). I don't see how this is confidential or prerelease information.

Comment: @Tim: Security-scoped bookmarks just let you restore access that was already acquired at some point. When you pop open an NSOpenPanel and the user picks MyPage.html, you don't have a security-scoped bookmark to resolve.